# How to use setTimeout with document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I'm using that document.querySelectorAll to get all the .gva elements on the page. But these elements will appear slowly after 20 seconds. Is there a way to get document.querySelectorAll to run after 20 seconds?
This is my code:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.gva');
```

Thank for all.

Comment: Why not wait until they show up *and then* execute your code, instead of waiting for arbitrary time which may or may not be enough?

Comment: What is your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.gva');
},20000) //20 seconds
```